# Masking animation in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I was stuck lately looking for a specific effect to be executed in ios Swift. I have 2 UIImageView. The logo and the shine picture. I just want to make the shine effect slide across that logo. I hope you could help me.

To visualize it, here's the effect that I want to achieve. Thanks!

http://www.entheosweb.com/Flash/video_tutorials/shining_text_effect.asp

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)


        badge = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "page6Logo"))
        badge!.frame.origin.x = 53/2
        badge!.frame.origin.y = 408/2

        blur = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "page6blur"))
        blur!.frame.origin.x = badge!.frame.origin.x
        blur!.frame.origin.y = badge!.frame.origin.y

        self.addSubview(badge!)
        self.addSubview(blur!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `animateWithDuration` method of UIView, moving the image with the shine effect from left to right.

OBj-c code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f animations:^{
//Move the image view to 100, 100 over 10 seconds.
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height); 
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i can move the image but the masking effect was not achieve.

Comment: If the image with the effect has a transparent background you should see the effect. Link your images, so we could see better what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not allowed to post an image since I'm new on stackoverflow. To visualize it, this is the exact effect that I want to achieve. Thank you.   http://www.entheosweb.com/Flash/video_tutorials/shining_text_effect.asp

Comment: upload the images to another site and post a link here

Comment: This is the current image http://i1081.photobucket.com/albums/j342/Angelo_Lapus/current_zpsb9bc3ac3.jpg   and the 2nd one is the effect that I want to achieve.   http://i1081.photobucket.com/albums/j342/Angelo_Lapus/want_zps0ab06ccc.jpg